# How to get current Windows user name in ASP.NET Core 2.2, when web application runs as Administrator?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-2.2, windows-users

We have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web-application, hosted on IIS and run under **MyComputer\MyAdminUser** Windows user (with administrator permissions). I need to get the name of current Windows user, which are working with our application, f.ex. **MyComputer\MyClientUser**. All client users are local users (**MyComputer\ ...**). How can I do it?

I've tried to use different approaches, but noone brings me expected result (**MyClientUser**):

```
1. HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for '`Current`' and no accessible extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found...

```
2. Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

the same problem with `LogonUserIdentity`

```
3. Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```

the same problem with `ServerVariables`

```
4. Request.Headers
```

This list doesn't include any information about current Windows user

```
5. Environment.UserName
```

The result is **"MyAdminUser"**

```
6. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

The result is **"MyComputer\MyAdminUser"**

```
7. ManagementObjectCollection collection = 
      new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
      .Get();
   collection?.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>()?.First()?.Properties?["UserName"]?.Value
```

For Visual Studio result is correct (current Windows user), but on IIS the `Properties?["UserName"]?.Value` is null or empty (`Properties?["UserName"]?.Name` = `"UserName"`)

What am I doing wrong and how can I get expected name?

Comment: You'll need to implement [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) in your ASP.NET Core application.

Comment: @Knelis is it possible to combine Windows Authentication with Individual User Accounts, which have been already implemented in this web-app (AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and so on)?

Comment: @Knelis I need just current Windows user's name, nothing more. Everything else works with Individual User Accounts

Comment: None of the above should be used. For ASP.NET Core, use `ControllerBase.User` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.user?view=aspnetcore-2.2